# Cannot install Hyperledger composer-cli

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm starting to build an app on Hyperledger Composer following these [instructions](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html), however when I run:

```
$ ./createPeerAdminCard.sh
```

I get this :

> `"Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control`
>
> `Running 'createPeerAdminCard.sh'`
>
> `FABRIC_VERSION is unset, assuming hlfv11`
>
> `FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)`
>
> `No version of composer-cli has been detected, you need to install composer-cli at v0.19 or higher."`

However, I have already installed it using:

```
$ npm install -g composer-cli
```

And I have got:

> `+ composer-cli@0.19.2
>   added 568 packages from 473 contributors in 58.747s`

Please help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nvm` should be managing your path for you so you don't have to worry about this. It would be worth checking first that you have installed node using nvm and which version is currently active

`nvm ls` will display versions of node installed

`nvm current` will display the currently active version

If it still doesn't work then you need to check your PATH to see if the correct path is present and add it manually if not. In your case the correct path would be

`/home/arnaud/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/bin`

You should also check that the version of node you are using is definitely the one installed via nvm.

Comment: Thanks David. Only one version of node is installed on my computer : v8.11.1 and the PATH has been correctly managed by nvm. I'm lost !

Comment: Some commands you can try.
1) composer -v

2) which composer

3) ls  -al /home/arnaud/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/bin

1. to see if composer is picked up on the path
2. to see where that version of composer is if it can find it
3. The contents of the bin directory where the composer command should be

Comment: Here are the results, everything looks normal doesn ‘t it ?
1. Composer version 1.6.4 2018-04-13 12:04:24
2. /home/arnaud/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/bin/composer
3. total 34036
drwxrwxr-x 2 arnaud arnaud     4096 avril 26 13:31 .
drwxrwxr-x 7 arnaud arnaud     4096 avril 26 12:57 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 arnaud arnaud       39 avril 26 13:20 composer -> ../lib/node_modules/composer-cli/cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 arnaud arnaud       46 avril 26 13:31 composer-playground -> ../lib/node_modules/composer-playground/cli.js

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 arnaud arnaud       47 avril 26 13:24 composer-rest-server -> ../lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/cli.js
-rwxrwxr-x 1 arnaud arnaud 34841540 mars  30 00:40 node
lrwxrwxrwx 1 arnaud arnaud       38 avril 26 12:59 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 arnaud arnaud       38 avril 26 12:59 npx -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 arnaud arnaud       33 avril 26 13:29 yo -> ../lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 arnaud arnaud       46 avril 26 13:29 yo-complete -> ../lib/node_modules/yo/lib/completion/index.js

Comment: And here you can find the content of composer-cli/cli.js : https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-cli/cli.js . My problem is : when I make for example  "composer network", I receive the exception "Command network not found". composer-cli is invisible

Comment: The result from the `composer -v` command isn't the right version number. Looks like you have something completely different called `composer` installed.

Comment: You're right ! The other composer is in /usr/local/bin/ but this path comes after /home/arnaud/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/bin/ in my PATH. I don't understand why the correct composer doesn't own the priority

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try setting the `PATH` like this,

```
export PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"
```

Once done, try executing your script again,

```
$ ./createPeerAdminCard.sh
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks David ! But the package is already version 0.19.2. I tried your commands but it doesn't change anything. It seems like the installed package composer-cli is invisible ...

Comment: @ArnaudCarrere In that case, can you please check my updated post/solution given above?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work maybe because there is no npm folder in /usr/local/share... But when I have a look at the composer-cli installation, I can see this path /home/arnaud/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli . Should I add this to the PATH ?

Comment: Yes... You should!

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same issue. After following all steps as specified in [Installing the development environment](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html.)

while running :

```
$ ./createPeerAdminCard.sh
```

i got this  :

> "Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
>
> Running 'createPeerAdminCard.sh'
>
> FABRIC_VERSION is unset, assuming hlfv11
>
> FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)
>
> No version of composer-cli has been detected, you need to install composer-cli at v0.20 or higher."

The solution was slightly different. It may be useful to someone. Actually owner of .composer directory was set to root instead of login user. As soon as i changed the owner the command run like charm.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by others, one should have use `nvm`, at least in MacOS.

After installing `nvm`, you type `$ nvm install v8.15.1` (or other node versions, but I believe composer needs v8.x).

After this, just issue `npm install composer-cli` and it works like a charm.